# Referencing class with additional class

Tags: html, css

I've got a jquery slider function on a page, and when the slide rotates I need the style of a LI tag to change.

So when the slider goes onto a li the class looks like this:

```
<li class="first sliderkit-selected">
```

And when it moves off it looks like this:

```
<li class="first">
```

But when the class goes to "first sliderkit-selected" I need it to be referenced from the style sheet but not sure how it is constructed, so far I've played around with:

```
li.sliderkit-selected li.first {
    background-color: red;
}
```

But it doesn't seem to pick it up.

I know you could use a comma inbetween each class, but **I want a style to be referenced exclusively when those two class's are together**, if that makes any sense.

Thanks.

Comment: I think it is worth mentioning why your attempt did not work. `li.sliderkit-selected li.first` indicates that you want all list items with class first INSIDE of all list items with class sliderkit to be red. If you remove the class names it is like this. `li li { ... }`. Or if we change the tag names to `ul li { ... }` you can see what I mean. All of tag li inside of tag ul.

Comment: Excellent, thanks to all below! Did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `li.sliderit-selected.first`:

```
li.sliderkit-selected.first{
    background-color: red;
}
```

See also:

- [CSS Selectors Level 3: Class selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#class-html)

  > The following rule matches any `P` element whose `class` attribute has been assigned a list of whitespace-separated values that includes both `pastoral` and `marine`:

  ```
   p.pastoral.marine { color: green }
  ```

  > This rule matches when `class="pastoral blue aqua marine"` but does not match for `class="pastoral blue"`.

Answer (score 1):

To select a DOM element with multiple classes, concatenate the classes in the selector:

```
li.sliderkit-selected.first {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select an element with multiple classes, you simply append the classes with a dot, like this:

```
li.first.sliderkit-selected { /* your rules */ }
```

This means "a `li` tag with the class `first` *and* the class `sliderkit-selected`".

Answer (score 0):

You can write like this:

```
.sliderkit-selected.first {
    background-color: red;
}
```

**OR**

```
.first.sliderkit-selected {
    background-color: red;
}
```